# Copying a file from one folder to another (with error handler) using Java Eclipse

Tags: java, automation

I'm trying to copy a file from one folder to another using `Files.copy()` and I managed to do that successfully.

But, I want the code to be more flexible by having a message to say **"File move unsuccessful!"**, **"File already exists"**(if the file is already exists in that folder).

**Code:**

```
package practice;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;


public class test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Path source = Paths.get("C:\\Downloads\\fileinput\\fileinput.csv");
        Path destination = Paths.get("C:\\Downloads\\landingzone\\fileinput.csv");
        System.out.println("File is moved successful!");

        try {
            Files.copy(source, destination);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println("File move unsuccessful!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check file is exists at destination before initiating file copy process.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {

        Path source = Paths.get( "C:\\Downloads\\fileinput\\fileinput.csv" );
        Path destination = Paths.get( "C:\\Downloads\\landingzone\\fileinput.csv" );

        try {

            if ( Files.exists( destination ) ) { // check file is exists at destination

                System.out.println( "File exists already." );
            } else {

                Files.copy( source, destination );

                System.out.println( "File copied successfully" );
            }


        } catch ( IOException e ) {

            System.out.println( "File move unsuccessful!" );
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way to deal with errors is to catch exceptions that occur during that process. I am sure you will be able to do that once you study a little harder.

Here is a simple code of `try/catch` block you can use it to catch exceptions and see if the operation was successful or not.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        //These files do not exist in our example.
        FileSystem system = FileSystems.getDefault();
        Path original = system.getPath("C:\\programs\\mystery.txt");
        Path target = system.getPath("C:\\programs\\mystery-2.txt");

        try {
            //Throws an exception on error
            Files.copy(original, target);
        } catch (IOException ex) { 
            System.out.println("ERROR");
        }
    }
}
```

Moreover you should go through java docs for the `Files.copy()` method.